# What the R error argument "chart.series" is missing mean?

Tags: r

```
cmf <- c(68,72,72,74,72,69,75,75,72,73,70,71,71,72,73,72,70,72,73,74)
fans <- data.frame(cmf)
spc.chart.run(x=fans$cmf ,main = "Run Chart",xlab = "Time",ylab = "Criterion Measure",col= "blue",pch=19)
```

I try to enter the code above but I always get this error message:

```
Error in spc.chart.run(x = fans$cmf, type = "b", main = "Run Chart", xlab = "Time",  :
```

argument "chart.series" is missing, with no default**

Comment: Please always include non-base packages, e.g. for `spc.chart.run`.

Comment: As a hint, it seems you are using the function `spc.chart.run` without giving it crucial data, here the "chart.series". Maybe instead of `spc.chart.run(x=fans$cmf  ` try `spc.chart.run(chart.series=fans$cmf  ` but that's a complete guess. You should know why and how you want to use a specific function.